# cocos3d 3.1 on cocos2d2.x . rename layer causing crash

Tags: xcode, crash, cocos3d

I follow the Harry's cocos3d  tutorial.

New a helloworld template project named shapes:

It runs perfectly.

Then I rename shapesLayer :  refactor->rename it to MainLayer.

The app crashes:

```
cocos2d: cocos2d-iphone v2.1
cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
cocos2d: OS version: 7.1 (0x07010000)
cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Apple Computer, Inc.
cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple Software Renderer
cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-9.4.3
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: NO
2014-08-31 11:25:11.966 shapes[9466:60b] cocos2d: viewDidLoad
2014-08-31 11:25:11.967 shapes[9466:60b] cocos2d: animation started with frame interval: 60.00
2014-08-31 11:25:11.969 shapes[9466:60b] cocos2d: surface size: 640x960
[***ERROR***] MainLayer on (null) could not determine the appropriate class to instantiate to automatically populate the cc3Scene property.
2014-08-31 11:25:11.970 shapes[9466:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[MainLayer cc3SceneClass], /Users/yetao/Documents/shapes/cocos3d/cocos3d/cocos3d/Scenes/CC3Layer.m:106
2014-08-31 11:25:11.973 shapes[9466:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'See previous logged error.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0298f1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0270e8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0298f048 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x006ea4de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   shapes                              0x0005f565 -[CC3Layer cc3SceneClass] + 949
    5   shapes                              0x0005eff0 -[CC3Layer cc3Scene] + 80
    6   shapes                              0x00060ab3 -[CC3Layer updateViewport] + 611
    7   shapes                              0x00060718 -[CC3Layer contentSizeChanged] + 88
    8   shapes                              0x0005e50d -[CCLayer(CC3) setContentSize:] + 269
    9   shapes                              0x001ddeac -[CCLayer init] + 252
    10  shapes                              0x0005f6c6 -[CC3Layer init] + 86
    11  shapes                              0x0005e3e5 +[CCLayer(CC3) layer] + 69
    12  shapes                              0x0000412a -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 586
    13  UIKit                               0x017ee14f -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
    14  UIKit                               0x017eeaa1 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1810
    15  UIKit                               0x017f3667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    16  UIKit                               0x01807f92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
    17  UIKit                               0x01808555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    18  UIKit                               0x017f5250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x03ebcf02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x03ebca0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0290aca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0290a9db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0293568c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x029349d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x029347eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    26  UIKit                               0x017f2d9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    27  UIKit                               0x017f4f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    28  shapes                              0x00003d2c main + 92
    29  shapes                              0x00002cd5 start + 53
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) instantiate to automatically populate the cc3Scene property
```

I debug into it:

```
 CC3Layer* cc3Layer = [MainLayer layer];
```

it just crashes...

I rename it back to shapesLayer. It can work.

So how can I do the rename things and why it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

I am speechless about CC3Layer.m :

They need to share a same prefix.

MainLayer-> MainScene.
shapesLayer-> shapesScecne.

```
-(Class) cc3SceneClass {
    Class sceneClass = nil;
    NSString* baseName = nil;
    NSString* layerClassName = NSStringFromClass(self.class);

    // If layer class name ends in "Layer", strip it and try some combinations
    if ( [layerClassName hasSuffix: @"Layer"] ) {
        baseName = [layerClassName substringToIndex: (layerClassName.length - @"Layer".length)];

        // Try HelloLayer -> HelloScene
        sceneClass = NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@Scene", baseName]);
        if (sceneClass && [sceneClass isSubclassOfClass: CC3Scene.class]) return sceneClass;

        // Try HelloLayer -> Hello
        sceneClass = NSClassFromString(baseName);
        if (sceneClass && [sceneClass isSubclassOfClass: CC3Scene.class]) return sceneClass;
    }

    // Try Hello -> HelloScene (including HelloLayer -> HelloLayerScene)
    sceneClass = NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@Scene", layerClassName]);
    if (sceneClass && [sceneClass isSubclassOfClass: CC3Scene.class]) return sceneClass;

    CC3Assert(NO, @"%@ could not determine the appropriate class to instantiate to automatically populate the cc3Scene property.", self);
    return nil;
}
```

problem solved.

For other scene, I just add it in the openlayer part

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by being "speechless" about this. :^) Your custom `CC3Layer` and `CC3Scene` subclasses don't ***need*** to share a name prefix. But when they do, there is this added feature that allows you to avoid having to instantiate them separately and hook them together (ie- "It's not a bug, it's a feature!" ;^) ).

Comment: If you don't want to make use of this feature, then you can simply revert to instantiating your own instances of your `CC3Layer` and `CC3Scene` subclasses, and set `myLayer.cc3Scene = myScene`. Or override either the `cc3Scene` or `cc3SceneClass` property method in your `CC3Layer` subclass to automatically instantiate and attach whatever `CC3Scene` subclass you want. See notes for the `CC3Layer cc3SceneClass` property for more info on this.

Comment: Yes. I am doing that. Thx~